# how do I use my local drive folder as data source in datagrip?

Tags: sql, datasource, datagrip

Using Datagrip,
I wanna write sql code and take some aggregated data from my csv file saved in my local drive.

How do I point my folder as datasource in datagrip and import csv to there to run sql code?
I have csv files in my local drive but don't know how to set my folder as data source and import my csv files as tables to be used.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/importexport.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click on the schema and click on import data from file like below. You will see a window pop up where you specify separators, headers, etc along with a preview.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was actually wondering about connecting the local data source which is creating 'public' part in your screen shot. I managed to figure that out but thank you so much! I did what you suggested after creating my local data source using postgres.